# LocalStorage not working in iframe in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to use localstorage in an iframe I get an error in Google Chrome:

> Uncaught SecurityError: An attempt was made to break through the
>   security policy of the user agent.

This only happens if you have the "Block third party cookies and site content" option enabled.

**Here is an example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/gS3bF/1/

```
$("a").click(function () {

    localStorage.coolcoolcool="ahahahahhhahahah";

});
```

**Here is an example the same exact code working without an iframe:**

http://fiddle.jshell.net/gS3bF/1/show/

Comment: Always include the relevant markup and code **in the question itself**, don't just link.

Comment: I just found out it only doesnt work if you have "block third party cookies and site content" enabled.

Comment: If they don't want you setting site data on their computer, there's no stopping them.